# How to understand trait for implementing Actix Web middleware?

Tags: rust, traits, actix-web

I'm looking at [examples](https://github.com/actix/examples/blob/master/middleware/src/simple.rs) for how to implement a middleware in Actix Web. They show:

```
impl<S, B> Transform<S> for SayHi
where
    S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>,
    S::Future: 'static,
    B: 'static,
{
    type Request = ServiceRequest;
    type Response = ServiceResponse<B>;
    type Error = Error;
    type InitError = ();
    type Transform = SayHiMiddleware<S>;
    type Future = FutureResult<Self::Transform, Self::InitError>;

    fn new_transform(&self, service: S) -> Self::Future {
        ok(SayHiMiddleware { service })
    }
}
```

I'm having some trouble understanding the line:

```
S: Service<Request = ServiceRequest, Response = ServiceResponse<B>, Error = Error>
```

Is it saying that `S` is bound by the `Service` trait and in that trait there is a type named `Request` and in THIS case `Request` is actually a `ServiceRequest`?

If so, why is there a need to specify `type Request = ServiceRequest;` in the block?

Comment: Because both implementation of `Service` and `Transform` needs those associated types independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it saying that `S` is bound by the `Service` trait and in that trait there is a type named `Request` and in THIS case `Request` is actually a `ServiceRequest`?

There are two traits, `Transform` and `Service` which both have an associated type called `Request`. These aren't related.

> If so, why is there a need to specify `type Request = ServiceRequest;` in the block?

By writing this implementation of `Transform` for `SayHi`, you are actually *creating* that relationship. You have defined what these associated type are, for an implementation that is only valid when all of the conditions in the `where` clause are met.

Comment: Just do double check if I understand you. The line in my question says that the associated type (`Request` since there are several) of `Service` in this particular implementation is a `ServiceRequest`. The `type Request = ServiceRequest` in the impl block says that the associated type (`Request`) of `Transform` ALSO is a `ServiceRequest`.

Comment: @evading yup. That's about it.